# Apply a picture style to all pictures in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Is there an easy way to pro-actively or retro-actively apply a 'Picture Style' to all images stored in a word document?

I want to apply the 'Center Shadow Rectangle' picture style to all images that I add to a document without changing them 1 by 1.

Comment: You can certainly loop through them and apply the same code to each (though it will likely differ a little for inline vs text-wrapped shapes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture style concept only exists at the UI level. To apply it to an image, you will have to check the properties of the style in the UI and apply them one by one using VBA:

```
Sub FormatPictures()

    Dim oInlineShape As inlineShape
    For Each oInlineShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        ApplyPictureStyleToInlineShape oInlineShape
    Next

    Dim oShape As Shape
    For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        ApplyPictureStyleToShape oShape
    Next


End Sub

Sub ApplyPictureStyleToInlineShape(shape As inlineShape)

    ' borders
    shape.Borders.Enable = False

    ' fill
    shape.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

    ' line
    shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    ' shadow
    shape.Shadow.Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
    shape.Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
    shape.Shadow.ForeColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack

    shape.Shadow.Transparency = 0.3
    shape.Shadow.Size = 100
    shape.Shadow.Blur = 15
    shape.Shadow.OffsetX = 0
    shape.Shadow.OffsetY = 0

    ' reflection
    shape.Reflection.Type = msoReflectionTypeNone

    ' glow
    shape.Glow.Radius = 0
    shape.SoftEdge.Radius = 0

End Sub

Sub ApplyPictureStyleToShape(shape As shape)

    ' fill
    shape.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

    ' line
    shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    ' shadow
    shape.Shadow.Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
    shape.Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
    shape.Shadow.ForeColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack

    shape.Shadow.Transparency = 0.3
    shape.Shadow.Size = 100
    shape.Shadow.Blur = 15
    shape.Shadow.OffsetX = 0
    shape.Shadow.OffsetY = 0

    ' reflection
    shape.Reflection.Type = msoReflectionTypeNone

    ' glow
    shape.Glow.Radius = 0
    shape.SoftEdge.Radius = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! This will work except there's a slight bug/typo in FormatPictures().  This line "For Each shape In ActiveDocument.Shapes" should be changed to "For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes"  (with an 'o' in front = oShape)

Answer (score 1):

Just got inspired by you guys (and others, so Thanks all!), and made my own macro to format a selected pasted picture with a single border (0.75 pt width) and simple shadow offset by 3 pts...

I assigned that macro to an icon, and voila!

Once I paste my image (most of them are screenshot for procedures and documentation of systems).

Works well in Word 2010. 
I did not tested other versions ...

---

```
Sub FormatPictureWithLineAndShadow()
Dim oInlineShp As InlineShape
For Each oInlineShp In Selection.InlineShapes
    With oInlineShp
    'Line border
        With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        ' shadow
            .Shadow.Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
            .Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
            .Shadow.ForeColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack
            .Shadow.Transparency = 0.6
            .Shadow.Size = 100
            .Shadow.Blur = 5
            .Shadow.OffsetX = 3
            .Shadow.OffsetY = 3
            ' reflection
            .Reflection.Type = msoReflectionTypeNone
            ' glow
            .Glow.Radius = 0
            .SoftEdge.Radius = 0
End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works well if you have pre-selected all images. But what if there are images within the document, and you just want to run the macro against all images, but not the text, of the document? Can the macro be adjusted to loop through all images in a document, and apply the settings?

Comment: To add more info: the macro will fail if there are other 'image-like' objects in the document, such as (in my case) may horizontal rules (the document was an HTML doc which had <hr> inside). So the macro needs to only work on image-type objects. In my case, I removed all the <hr> codes, and the macro worked well.